# PHP - udiff compare multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, diff, array-difference

I have two multidimenzional arrays and I need to compare them. Problem is that each subarray is unique by combination of `permission_id`, `create` and `view`. And I need to compare this arrays to check if there is such a unique subarray. The keys of subarrays can be different. So far I have this:

```
$updated_permissions = array(
    0 => array(
        'create' => 0,
        'view' => 1,
        'permission_id' => "87"
    ),
    1 => array(
        'create' => 0,
        'view' => 1,
        'permission_id' => "11"
    ),
    2 => array(
        'create' => 1,
        'view' => 0,
        'permission_id' => "11"
    ),
    3 => array(
        'create' => 0,
        'view' => 1,
        'permission_id' => "18"
    )
);

$origin_permissions = array(
    0 => array(
        'create' => 0,
        'view' => 1,
        'permission_id' => "8"
    ),
    1 => array(
        'create' => 0,
        'view' => 1,
        'permission_id' => "11"
    ),
    2 => array(
        'create' => 1,
        'view' => 0,
        'permission_id' => "12"
    )
);

$arrdiff = array_merge(
    array_udiff($origin_permissions, $updated_permissions, 'udiffCompare'),
    array_udiff($updated_permissions, $origin_permissions, 'udiffCompare')
);

function udiffCompare($a, $b) {
    return $a['permission_id'] - $b['permission_id'];
}

print_r($arrdiff);
```

but that compare only `permission_id` so result is this:

```
[0] => Array (
    [create] => 0
    [view] => 1
    [permission_id] => 8
    )
[1] => Array (
    [create] => 1
    [view] => 0
    [permission_id] => 12
    )
[2] => Array (
    [create] => 0
    [view] => 1
    [permission_id] => 87
    )
[3] => Array (
    [create] => 0
    [view] => 1
    [permission_id] => 18
    )
```

while I need to compare also if `create` and `view` are same. So result I want to have is this (with `permission_id` 11 which has different `create` and `view`):

```
[0] => Array (
    [create] => 0
    [view] => 1
    [permission_id] => 8
    )
[1] => Array (
    [create] => 1
    [view] => 0
    [permission_id] => 12
    )
[2] => Array (
    [create] => 0
    [view] => 1
    [permission_id] => 87
    )
[3] => Array (
    [create] => 0
    [view] => 1
    [permission_id] => 18
    )
[4] => Array (
    [create] => 1
    [view] => 0
    [permission_id] => 11
    )
```

This code is also [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/d387-wzce)

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
function udiffCompare($a, $b) {
 if ($a['permission_id'] !== $b['permission_id'] || $a['view'] !== $b['view'] || $a['create'] !== $b['create']){
  return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: you could also just add all and return them

Comment: With this I got totally different result than I want.

Comment: Ok then do i understand it right, that you want to have all the entrys which have changed something ? no matter what has changed ?

Comment: I don't know how to explain better. Each subarray is unique by combination of permission_id, create and view so yes, if something is different, then it mean that is another unique subarray.

Comment: Ok i know what you need, but can you try the updated code above and tell my what is wrong with the result ?

Comment: Still same problem. When you try to dump it then there is no permission_id 11 which is different (has another create and view) which I need in result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88455/discussion-between-doktor-oswaldo-and-draffix).